# WCF : Why I can't send a List of objects to my webservice

Tags: c#, list, wcf

I build a List of objects : `List<Mandat>`

And I call my webservice Like these :

```
ServiceGestionClient svc = new ServiceGestionClient();
svc.setNewMandatImage(listMandat);
```

In my Webservice I have these :

```
public void setNewMandatImage(List<Mandat> mi)
```

But i have These error :

```
Unable to convert from list<Mandat> to mandat[]
```

Why does he try to convert as an array ?

Comment: Just use  `listMandat.ToArray()`. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.toarray

Comment: Where does the error originate from? Client/server? And where exactly. A stack trace would be helpful...

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that WCF serializes the universal list into an array to send over the network. The configuration just tells svcutil to create a proxy and convert them back to a common list for convenience.

**solution:**

Set in the Add Service Reference tool:

[image]

[image]

Finally, apply this setting to generate a proxy class.

Feel free to let me know if the problem persists.