# Generated WCF proxy returns null for a list

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, soap, wsdl

We are trying to implement a WCF proxy/client for a PHP SOAP service.
We retrieved the WSDL and created a service reference in a command line application.
We are able to retrieve the result of a SOAP operation, but it turns out that returned lists always end up as null, when tapping the wire with fiddler or test it in SoapUI we can clearly see data being returned.

I've followed a few advices in similar issue posts and came up with a minimalistic deserialization example that seems to have the same issue.

```cs
Message m = Message.CreateMessage(XmlReader.Create("response.xml"), int.MaxValue, MessageVersion.Soap11);
SoapReflectionImporter importer = new SoapReflectionImporter(new SoapAttributeOverrides(), "http://brokenns");
XmlTypeMapping mapping = importer.ImportTypeMapping(typeof(getDeviceListResponse));
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(mapping);
getDeviceListResponse response = (getDeviceListResponse)serializer.Deserialize(m.GetReaderAtBodyContents());
Console.WriteLine(response.@return.deviceList == null  ? "List is null" : "List is not null");
```

```
< List is null
```

service.wsdl

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
  xmlns:tns="http://brokenns" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
  targetNamespace="http://brokenns">
  <types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://brokenns">
      <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" />
      <xsd:complexType name="Device">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:complexType name="DeviceListResult">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="message" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
          <xsd:element name="deviceList" type="tns:Device" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:schema>
  </types>
  <message name="getDeviceListRequest">
    <part name="loadSimCard" type="xsd:boolean" />
  </message>
  <message name="getDeviceListResponse">
    <part name="return" type="tns:DeviceListResult" />
  </message>
  <portType name="DevicesServicePortType">
    <operation name="getDeviceList">
      <documentation>Returns device list</documentation>
      <input message="tns:getDeviceListRequest" />
      <output message="tns:getDeviceListResponse" />
    </operation>
  </portType>
  <binding name="DevicesServiceBinding" type="tns:DevicesServicePortType">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <operation name="getDeviceList">
      <soap:operation soapAction="https://myservice.com/ws/devices.php/getDeviceList" style="rpc" />
      <input>
      <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://brokenns" /></input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://brokenns" /></output>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="DevicesService">
    <port name="DevicesServicePort" binding="tns:DevicesServiceBinding">
      <soap:address location="https://myservice.com/ws/devices.php" />
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

response.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:getDeviceListResponse xmlns:ns1="http://brokenns">
            <return>
                <message>works</message>
                <deviceList>
                    <id>48</id>
                </deviceList>
                <deviceList>
                    <id>41</id>
                </deviceList>
                <deviceList>
                    <id>42</id>
                </deviceList>
            </return>
        </ns1:getDeviceListResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Can anybody spot the error in the service wsdl that would render my list null after deserialisation?

I've tried doing a simple back and forth serialisation with the generated contracts and couldn't spot an issue there, makes me believe it has something to do with the namespaces, omitting them didn't help though.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<getDeviceListResponse xmlns:ns1="http://brokenns">
  <return>
    <message>sd</message>
    <deviceList>
      <id>2323</id>
    </deviceList>
    <deviceList>
      <id>67</id>
    </deviceList>
  </return>
</getDeviceListResponse>
```

Comment: The reason may be that WCF serializes the universal list into an array to send over the network. The configuration just tells svcutil to create a proxy and convert them back to a common list for convenience. You can try to modify the collection type when you created a service reference. For more information about it, you can refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63702018/wcf-why-i-cant-send-a-list-of-objects-to-my-webservice/63716002#comment112679937_63716002

Comment: None of the collection type change the fact that the list is null after deserialisation within the wcf proxy.

Comment: Do you want to call PHP SOAP Service in .net? If you want to call PHP SOAP Service in .net you can refer to this link: https://forums.asp.net/t/1066611.aspx?Consuming+a+PHP+Web+Service+from+a+NET+client

Comment: The service is indeed using NuSoap on the other end, but the link has no answer for me.

Answer (score -1):

The following works with serialization :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));
            Envelope envelope = (Envelope)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Envelope
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public Body Body { get; set; }
    }
    public class Body
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "getDeviceListResponse", Namespace = "http://brokenns")]
        public getDeviceListResponse getDeviceListResponse { get; set; }
    }
    public class getDeviceListResponse
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "return", Namespace = "")]
        public Return Return { get; set; }
    }
    public class Return
    {
        public string message { get; set; }
        [XmlElement()]
        public List<deviceList> deviceList { get; set; }
    }
    public class deviceList
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I am aware the contracts work in plain XMLSerializer. It doesn't work in an automatically generated service proxy for said WSDL.
I found https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/25245 with a similar issue, makes me wonder if having repeating elements mixed with other properties in wcf contracts without a wraping element is not possible at all...

Comment: The WSDL isn't complete.  There are errors in the WSDL.  For example there is no  type="tns:Device"complex element

Comment: I did in fact trim the wsdl down, but there is an Device complex element right above the DeviceListResult type. 
https://www.wsdl-analyzer.com/service/service/1766269158?version=1
https://www.wsdl-analyzer.com/schema/show/1766269158?version=1&targetNamespace=http%3A%2F%2Fbrokenns

Comment: With a difference prefix.  One is in WSDL is using TNS.  I tried creating classes from the WSDL Schema and it failed.

Comment: Generating the classes with "svcutil file.wsdl" from a Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise command prompt sucessfully generates me a DevicesService.cs containing a class DeviceListResult and referencing a class Device in its property deviceList.

Comment: Does classes look like my classes?  I was getting an error with xsd.exe there was not root element.  I think my error was due to you editing the files.  You need to compare my classes with the svcutil results to see if prefixes and namespaces match my classes.  I think there is a mismatch against between the WSDL schema and the acutal xml file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224991/discussion-between-sven-mawby-and-jdweng).